# Problem writing this query in mysql (marking read messages in a forum)

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

Hey. i am writing a forum, and i have this table that marks messages a specific user read:

```
`read_messages`(`message_id`,`user_id`)
```

a simplified version of the messages table:

```
`messages`(`id`,`forum_id`,`author_id`)
```

now, i want to be able, when retrieving the message data from the database for a given forum, to add a variable that will tell me if the current user has read that message or not. i know how to do this with 2 queries (1st i retrieve all messages, then i check for each of them if the user has read them), but no clue as to how to join them together. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT messages.*, read_messages.id as read_id
FROM messages 
LEFT OUTER JOIN read_messages 
   ON ( messages.id = read_messages.message_id AND read_messages.user_id  = [ USER ID ] )
```

If `read_id` is returned as a number > 0 rather than `NULL`,  then the message has been read because there is a corresponding record in `read_messages` for that user.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're after an Outer Join, check out the [Outer Joins Section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) for the syntax, which allows you to select all values from one table and NULLS where the values don't exist.